# multiple character replacement in matrix in python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I am still learning python and I have a vector which belongs to a pretty big matrix and the entries in this vector are of object type. They are ('< 1 year', '1 year', '2 years' and so on)
I would like to change it into 0, 1, 2, 3 respectively. I wrote the following lines which work but there has to be more simple solution which doesn't require a loop with 10 conditions:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

data_file = pd.read_csv('loan.csv')

emp_length=data_file.emp_length
emp_len=[]
for i in range(len(emp_length)):
   if emp_length[i]=='< 1 year':
       emp_len.append(0)
   elif emp_length[i]=='1 year':
       emp_len.append(1)
   elif emp_length[i]=='2 years':
       emp_len.append(2)
   elif emp_length[i]=='3 years':
       emp_len.append(3)
   elif emp_length[i]=='4 years':
       emp_len.append(4)
   elif emp_length[i]=='5 years':
       emp_len.append(5)
   elif emp_length[i]=='6 years':
       emp_len.append(6)
   elif emp_length[i]=='7 years':
       emp_len.append(7)
   elif emp_length[i]=='8 years':
       emp_len.append(8)
   elif emp_length[i]=='9 years':
       emp_len.append(9)
   elif emp_length[i]=='10+ years':
       emp_len.append(10)
   else:
       emp_len.append(0)
```

I don't need to create the new vector but this was the solution I was able to come up with by myself. If there is anyway to replace those entries in the same vector it would be even better. Thank you for any suggestions and help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the dataframe `df`

```
np.random.seed([3,1415])
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(emp_length=np.random.choice(list(m.keys()), 20)))
print(df)

   emp_length
0    < 1 year
1     2 years
2   10+ years
3   10+ years
4     7 years
5   10+ years
6     3 years
7     8 years
8     7 years
9   10+ years
10   < 1 year
11    6 years
12    8 years
13    6 years
14   < 1 year
15  10+ years
16    2 years
17   < 1 year
18    4 years
19    9 years
```

You could use `map` or `replace` with a dictionary

```
m = {
   '< 1 year': 0,
   '1 year': 1,
   '2 years': 2,
   '3 years': 3,
   '4 years': 4,
   '5 years': 5,
   '6 years': 6,
   '7 years': 7,
   '8 years': 8,
   '9 years': 9,
   '10+ years': 10
}

data_file.emp_length.map(m)
# or equivalently
# data_file.emp_length.replace(m)

0      0
1      2
2     10
3     10
4      7
5     10
6      3
7      8
8      7
9     10
10     0
11     6
12     8
13     6
14     0
15    10
16     2
17     0
18     4
19     9
Name: emp_length, dtype: int64
```

---

You could also use a categorical type

```
cats = ['< 1 year', '1 year', '2 years', '3 years', '4 years', '5 years', '6 years', '7 years', '8 years', '9 years', '10+ years']
c = df.emp_length.astype('category', categories=cats, ordered=True)
print(c)

0      < 1 year
1       2 years
2     10+ years
3     10+ years
4       7 years
5     10+ years
6       3 years
7       8 years
8       7 years
9     10+ years
10     < 1 year
11      6 years
12      8 years
13      6 years
14     < 1 year
15    10+ years
16      2 years
17     < 1 year
18      4 years
19      9 years
Name: emp_length, dtype: category
Categories (11, object): [< 1 year < 1 year < 2 years < 3 years ... 7 years < 8 years < 9 years < 10+ years]
```

Then you could access the mapped integers with

```
c.cat.codes

0      0
1      2
2     10
3     10
4      7
5     10
6      3
7      8
8      7
9     10
10     0
11     6
12     8
13     6
14     0
15    10
16     2
17     0
18     4
19     9
dtype: int8
```

Comment: great! thank you very much although i think pd.factorize will not work because in case of '10+ years' for example it will return 1 but map was very helpful

Comment: It's a great answer  !